# How to execute controller methods on ajax call?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

In Marionette or Backbone, routes executes when change url in navigation field. Is any way to execute routes on ajax call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to trigger a route change you can do something like below which is not recommended:

```
yourRouterInstance.navigate("your_url_that_is_mapped",{trigger:true});
```

Instead you need to decouple the route navigation,data loading and view creation and also achieve the same effect.

1. Create a controller JS Object.
2. Extend this object with `Backbone.Events`.

   ```
   var AppController = _.extend({},Backbone.Events);
   ```
3. Create method on this object and bind them to an event.
   3.1 Each of this method will load appropriate data thru `ajax` that is required.
   3.2 Create an instance of the appropriate `view`.
   3.3 Pass the loaded data to the instance of the `view`
   3.4 Call the `navigate` method and update the url to the appropriate url.

   ```
   AppController.on("any_custom_event",function(payload) {
       // MAKE THE AJAX CALL.
       // AFTER SUCCESSFUL CALL INSTANTIATE THE VIEW AND PASS THE DATA .
       // CALL yourAppRouter.navigate("your_current_url",{trigger:false});
   });
   ```
4. Trigger this custom events from route callbacks / where ever required.

   ```
   //in router callbacks
   AppController.trigger("any_custom_event",payload); 

   // In other places  where required like inside an ajax success call back:
   AppController.trigger("any_custom_event",payload);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

From the Backbone docs:

> ### navigate
>
> #### router.navigate(fragment, [options])
>
> Whenever you reach a point in your application that you'd like to save as a URL, call **navigate** in order to update the URL. If you wish to also call the route function, set the **trigger** option to `true`. To update the URL without creating an entry in the browser's history, set the replace option to `true`.

In an ajax callback you can, therefore, do something like,

```
$.ajax({
  success: function () {
    app.navigate('path/to/your/route', {trigger: true})
  }
})
```

Or using native JS (supported everywhere), you can just change the hash yourself:

```
$.ajax({
  success: function () {
    window.location = '#your/route/path/';
  }
})
```

That will also trigger the route path.

Both solutions will save the route in your browser's back history.